# shufler() takes exactly 1 positional argument (2 given)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Below is my code.

```
def __init__(self):
    self.node=[]
    self.fronts=[]
    self.GoalNode=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','0']
    self.StartNode=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','0']
    self.PreviousNode=[]
    self.prePreviousNode=[]
    self.PreviousCount=1

def Solve(self):
    self.shufler(10)
    ......


def shufler(self):

        while True:
            node=self.StartNode
```

And below is the error message I received:

```
File "E:\Zoe's file\CMPT 310\Assign 2\astart8puzzle\AI8puzzle\py8puzzel.py", line 18, in Solve
    self.shufler(10)
TypeError: shufler() takes exactly 1 positional argument (2 given)
```

I don't understand where I gave 2 arguments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
self.shufler(10)
```

This calls `shufler` with two arguments, (1) `self` and (2) `10`. The object to the left of the `.` is used as the first argument.

To handle the `10` argument, add a second parameter to `shufler`'s definition:

```
def shufler(self, count):
```

Comment: @zoe, it's considered polite in S.O. to mark a question that answered your question as 'accepted'.  There's a faded checkbox that only you can see to indicate it's accepted.

Comment: ya I will accept it in 2 mins. The website is not allowing me to do so yet. Guess u answered too fast:P